# How can we control creating number of connections in mongodb by C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

My application is creating 800 `mongodb` connections in a day, but only 300 users login in my application a day.

> How Can I use connection pooling in C# for mongoDB so that number of established connections will be reduced?

Comment: Usually MongoClient class handles the pooling internally.
You will have to be more specific about your problem... and provide some code if possible.

Comment: Is there a problem with that number of connections?  MongoDB handles them differently to SQL Server (for instance).

Comment: this sounds like a user / coding issue in regards to how you are creating connections and disposing of the connections. when you create a connection are you using the `using () {}` construct..? hard to tell what you're doing if we can't see examples of how your are creating the connection

Comment: Do you mind sharing some code?